# NSTextfield isBordered property getting reset

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using a nib/xib and want to identify if a particular NSTextfield has a border set.

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray array];

[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:nil topLevelObjects:&objects];
for (NSObject *obj in objects)
{
    if ( [obj isKindOfClass:[NSView class]] )
    {
        mainView = (NSView *)obj;
        break;
    }
}

for (NSView *view in [mainView subviews])
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]])
    {
        NSTextField *label = (NSTextField*)view;
        NSLog(@"view is bordered: %d", label.isBordered);
    }
}
```

The textfields are shown correctly bordered or not in IB, but when the above code runs, it always reports false for bordered regardless of whether it is bordered or not. I've tried using NSControl instead of NSView in the for loop, but this makes no difference.

How can I correctly identify the 'isBordered' state? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
label.bezeled
label.bezelStyle

NSTextFieldSquareBezel  = 0,
NSTextFieldRoundedBezel = 1
```

**UPDATE:**
NSTextField has 4 [borderStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmReQ.png)

1. isBordered = NO;  isBezeled = YES; BezelStyle = 0;
2. isBordered = NO;  isBezeled = NO;  BezelStyle = 0;
3. isBordered = YES; isBezeled = NO;  BezelStyle = 0;
4. isBordered = NO;  isBezeled = YES; BezelStyle = 1;

Information about this can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj5nR.png)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at these. Bezeled is always false as well. bezelStyle can be non-zero even when the textfield has no border.

Comment: Ah, I was getting my bezels and borders mixed up! Thanks, @Vladimir Prigarin.